# Can anyone recognize this app (toggles WiFi, GPS, Sync, BT, etc.) in the notification bar?

Tags: notification-bar

I found this screenshot in one of the market apps ([Galaxy Nexus Flashlight](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nionsoftware.flashlight)), in the red rectangle there is an app do you know this app? it seem very interesting.

[image]

Comment: CyanogenMod 7.1's Power Control can be made to look like that. Might be the same software as described in the answers.

Comment: CyberShadow: I will look into that, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks a lot everyone, I found it, it's a custom ROM called AOKP http://www.forum.aokp.co

Answer (score 4):

If you're thinking about installing it, I'd recommend you to use [Widgetsoid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jim2). It can sit on homescreen and as notification (like in image). And, it provides a lot of toggles which -- I bet -- no other app provides.

Answer (score 2):

the correct answer: this is an app called [TogglePanel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.seifsoft.togglepanel&hl=en) that appears in the notification pull down.  It costs $1.

Answer (score 1):

This is the built-in `Power Widget` of the Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich).

In other ROMs it's called something like `Power Control` or `Toggle Buttons`.

But as an APP there is a very good Application called [Power Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.siriusapplications.eclairwidgets) which has a free and paid version.

Comment: this is not a **built-in Power Widget of the Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich)**