# How to toggle wi-fi, gps etc quickly in HTC Sense?

Tags: settings, htc-sense, notification-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can anyone recognize this app (toggles WiFi, GPS, Sync, BT, etc.) in the notification bar?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20733/can-anyone-recognize-this-app-toggles-wifi-gps-sync-bt-etc-in-the-notific)

I am used to from cyanogen mod to be able to toggle on/off wi-fi, gps, data, plane mode etc Also I was able to configure what is going to be available to toggle.

Now in HTC Sense version 4.0 that runs on Android 4.0.3 I cannot find anything like that.

Do I have to install (and probably pay) for a widget or I missed this a must feature in the Sense?

Could you recommend a widget that would allow me to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of toggle switches available. Some even come pre-installed -- just check it out:

1. go to your homescreen
2. long-press on an empty space
3. select to add a widget
4. scroll through the list of available widgets
5. select the one you want to use

Usually, there are a lot of separate widgets to toggle *either* Wifi, GPS, ... -- but also a "power-widget" (or "energy-widget") should be available, which is a combination of several widgets.

If you are still not satisfied with what you find there, the playstore is full of alternatives:

- [Elixir 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bartat.android.elixir) with its [Elixir 2 - Widgets](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bartat.android.elixir.widget) being the most famous and high-rated<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qihCW.jpg)</sup>, and can even be integrated into the notification area
- [Power Toggles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.painless.pc) being another alternative<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmTbg.jpg)</sup> -- also can be integrated with the notification area

Just to give you two examples -- as said, the playstore has many more. Below you find a screenshot from *Elixir*<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qihCW.jpg)</sup> and *Power Toggles*<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmTbg.jpg)</sup>, to give you an idea of what they can do.

[image: Elixir 2] [image: Power Toggles]

Comment: Any idea if or how I can customize HTC widgets? They do what I want but I need to used like 3 of them. One doesn't airplane, the other one gps ....